Android app throws NoClassDefFoundError after setting Gradle SourceSets
I am trying to understand how to set sourcesets in build.gradle.kts file. For that i have a test project. The project structure is as follows-
app
-src
--main
---java
----com.example.myapplication
-----MainActivity.kt
--sample2
---java
----com.example.myapp.legacy
-----LegacyFile.java
LegacyFile.java
package com.example.myapp.legacy;

public class LegacyFile {

}

Here, i wan to create instance of LegacyFile inside MainActivity.kt file -
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
....
        val legacyFile = LegacyFile()
} 

So, i added the following lines to app/build.gradle.kts file -
android {
.....
    sourceSets.getByName("main").apply {
        kotlin.setSrcDirs(listOf("src/sample2/java"))
    } 
}

Now, the project compiles successfully. But, when i run the app it throws an exception -

FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.myapplication, PID: 2436
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of:
Lcom/example/myapp/legacy/LegacyFile;
at
com.example.myapplication.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.kt:25)
..... Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class
"com.example.myapp.legacy.LegacyFile" on path: DexPathList[[dex file
"/data/data/com.example.myapplication/code_cache/.overlay/base.apk/classes5.dex",
zip file
"/data/app/~~5E7UPyWAZdlsGbzLHVOIJw==/com.example.myapplication-kmtHz5UXr_gzaXYqPtpKyA==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/~~5E7UPyWAZdlsGbzLHVOIJw==/com.example.myapplication-kmtHz5UXr_gzaXYqPtpKyA==/lib/x86_64,
/system/lib64, /system_ext/lib64]]

When i inspect the apk file, i can see LegacyFile -

Can someone please explain what i am doing wrong here?
Thanks!

Update to this:
android {
.....
    sourceSets.getByName("main") {
        java.srcDir("src/sample2/java")
    } 
}

or
android {
.....
    sourceSets.getByName("main") {
        java.srcDirs += ['src/sample2/java']
    } 
}

FYI: kotlin.srcDirs didn't work because you are trying to source .java files instead of .kt files.

Thanks @Anish B. It works! But i have one question, it works when i add path to java.srcDirs, but not when i add to kotlin.srcDirs? any ideas?

@user1122549 I think kotlin.srcDirs didn't work because those are java files not kotlin files

okay i tried sourcing .kt files with javaj.srDirs and it works. However, the reverse was not true. I can source .kt files with kotin.srcDirs but not .java files. Thanks for your help! :)
